# CSS how to place an image to the right of variable width text on roll over?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu of text with variable widths eg:

```
Home
Services
About Us
Contact
```

How can I position an image to the right of the different width text on hover in css? **Is it possible without using a fixed width?**

```
Home
Services •
About Us
Contact
```

or

```
Home
Services
About Us
Contact •
```

Comment: yes its possible in css.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/RrRtqfVf

Do this one

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>

</ul>
```

Css

```
    ul{
list-style:none;

}
li{
position:relative;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
li:hover:after{
content:'';
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  right:-20px;
  top:5px;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/RrRtqfVf)**

Comment: Hi this is good, does after work with all browsers? Also can I replace the * with an image or background image?

Comment: yes if u used to image than used to background image as like this  li:hover:after{content:''; background:url('some.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;}

Comment: But if you have words of different length it doesn't do what you asked, as far as I can see. -> http://tinkerbin.com/Znxb5nhU

Comment: @williamsongibson this is demo http://tinkerbin.com/RrRtqfVf   and adjust the width or height according your design image and replace the background color into background image.................

Comment: Perfect! I tweaked it slightly: http://tinkerbin.com/ZF5CM0Zh thank you for your help Rohit!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
<li>Services</li>
<li>About Us</li>
   <li> Contact</li>
</ul>
```

​CSS

```
ul{width:80px}
ul li:hover{background:url(http://hotels.online.com.sg/DB/icon/star_icon2.gif) right no-repeat}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A4rdt/)

Comment: This aligns all images to the same value on the right. This is not what I asked. The text is variable width, so the image should always be 5px from the end of the word, not fixed 80px as your example above.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, use `background-image`..

Lets assume this is your html:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Now, use this CSS to achieve what you want:

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
ul li{width:120px;}
ul li:hover{background:url(your/image/path) no-repeat top right;}
```

If you want different image/icon to each item in your menu, use `attributes` or other class's:

```
<ul>
    <li data="home">Home</li>
    <li data="services">Services</li>
    <li data="about">About Us</li>
    <li data="contact">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And your CSS should look like:

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
ul li{width:120px;}
ul li[data="home"]:hover{background:url(your/image/path1) no-repeat top right;}
ul li[data="services"]:hover{background:url(your/image/path2) no-repeat top right;}
ul li[data="about"]:hover{background:url(your/image/path3) no-repeat top right;}
ul li[data="contact"]:hover{background:url(your/image/path4) no-repeat top right;}
```

Comment: Wow! What is 'data=' ? I've not seen that before? Does it work in all browsers?

Comment: Yep.. this is attributes.. and you can select them with css

Comment: Thanks, for this, but your example sets the image to a fixed position to the right (120px), I want the image to be placed 5px to the right, depending on the width of the text before it. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah of course.. remove the `width` from the `li` and give the `li` padding right that will be calculated like this: iconwidth px + 5px

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't you be using "data-_yourpropertyhere_" instead of just "data"? I don't think "data" alone is an accepted attribute, while HTML5 does specify that you can use your own custom attributes by appending "data-" to it.